# Копирование скомпилированного проекта из Java

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени суток господа. (первые шаги в java)

Есть такая штука 'IntelliJ Idea 12', пишем программу, нажимаем запустить - все работает.

Вопрос: как эту самую программу (скомпилированную) перенести в любое нужное для меня место? допустим на флешку/диск/и_т.д.

p.s. имеется ввиду не копирование проекта а запускающий файл + файлы программы. Сам нашел только файлы типа *.java, и что есть моя программа - не понял. Искал что то в роде* .exe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. В Java запускаемым является набор объектных файлов `*.class` - в IDEA они обычно лежат в каталоге `out`.
2. На практике, это не очень удобно таскать с собой целое дерево объектных файлов и поэтому их упаковывают `jar` файл - по сути архив. IDEA естественно умеет упаковывать объектные файлы в `jar` файл. Как это делать [объяснено в мануале](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/packaging-a-module-into-a-jar-file.html)
3. В принципе можно упаковать `jar` в исполняемый файл `exe` - то есть придать некий исполняемый заголовок, который будет подсовывать JVM объектники/jar - именно об этом написано в посте [[@voipp](/users/12796/voipp)](/users/12796/voipp)

P.S. Надеюсь понятно, что без JVM исполняемый файл (неважно какой) не будет работать. Наличие JVM гарантируется установкой JRE.

Comment: Эммм.. берем исходник из папки 'out'. Отлично. Один пункт есть! Далее нажимаем build -> и..? Максимум, что там есть Generate and Build. Про Jar ничего не сказано. Мануал ест-но такого не описывает. Да и сам Generate and Build - Jar файлы не форминует. Только два '*.xml' и '*.properties'

Что делать?

Comment: @mixalef господи, как же вы бесконечно далеки... ужос просто - ужос. Неужели не можете просто прочитать мануал? `Project structure->Artifacts->+->Jar->From module with dependencies` - ну на крайняк есть же гугель, который [в первой же ссылке кидает](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)

Comment: согласен, надо исправляться. То, что легко давалось в С++ (2 клавиши и готов .exe) приходиться выковыривать в java. А за терпение и ответ спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

вот что вам поможет, там легко разобраться самому : [нажми на меня](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)